# Parse nested json with python - full beginner

Tags: python, json

I am a complete beginner with the python json module.
I am trying to access nested values in the json file below, such as for example "degrees" and define variables within my code.

Can anyone help me? I've been looking for the past hour but nothing works...

```
    {
  "results": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "wind": {
        "degrees": 210,
        "speed_kts": 23,
        "speed_mph": 26,
        "speed_mps": 12,
        "gust_kts": 34,
        "gust_mph": 39,
        "gust_mps": 17
      },
      "temperature": {
        "celsius": 12,
        "fahrenheit": 54
      },
      "dewpoint": {
        "celsius": 5,
        "fahrenheit": 41
      },
      "humidity": {
        "percent": 63
      },
      "barometer": {
        "hg": 29.88,
        "hpa": 1012,
        "kpa": 101.19,
        "mb": 1011.92
      },
      "visibility": {
        "miles": "Greater than 6",
        "miles_float": 6.21,
        "meters": "10,000+",
        "meters_float": 10000
      },
      "elevation": {
        "feet": 357.61,
        "meters": 109
      },
      "location": {
        "coordinates": [
          2.55,
          49.012798
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "icao": "LFPG",
      "observed": "2020-01-15T13:00:00.000Z",
      "raw_text": "LFPG 151300Z 21023G34KT CAVOK 12/05 Q1012 NOSIG",
      "station": {
        "name": "Charles de Gaulle International"
      },
      "clouds": [
        {
          "code": "CAVOK",
          "text": "Clear skies"
        }
      ],
      "flight_category": "VFR",
      "conditions": []
    }
  ]
}
```

My current code is the following:

```
import requests
import json

hdr = my_header_here
req = requests.get("url", headers=hdr)

metarJSON = json.loads(req.text)
```

What I am trying to do is

```
print(metarJSON["data"][0]["wind"]["degrees"])
```

Thank you so much in advance, I am a full beginner with python as of last week :)

Comment: `print(metarJSON["data"][0]["wind"]["degrees"])` should do. What's the issue with it?

Comment: It gives me TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Not with the given example JSON. Explore the dict step by step. `print(metarJSON)`, `print(metarJSON['data'])`, … what does each step give you and where does it start to complain?

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads()` parses json string and returns a dictionary , so you can access to values in this way :

```
parsed = json.loads(req.text)

parsed = json.loads(a)
for item in parsed["data"] :
    if "wind" in item :
        print(item["wind"]["degrees"])
```

Comment: That is one of the things I tried to do but it gave me the following error: print(metarJSON["data"]["wind"]["degrees"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: if you have to do this more often, look at glom. https://github.com/mahmoud/glom which makes json parsing more fun.